# I can't capture enter key in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using select2, and I need to capture the enter key, but I can't.

I used:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.select2-input', function (ev) {

   if (ev.which == 13) {
     alert('press enter')     
   }

   if (ev.which == 9) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
     alert('press tab')                
 }
});
```

I can capture all the keys but for the enter.

Can someone help me?

Comment: It works fine for me. Instead of alerting `'press enter'`, try alerting `ev.which` without the `if` statement.

Comment: the problem is, the event never fire when press enter inside the select2

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with your code and it seems to work. https://jsfiddle.net/ricardonunez/eqqoy3ku/

Comment: you have this in the head tag, right?  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: the problem is when i did submit on select2, never fire the keydown or keyup or keypress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$('select2-search-field > input.select2-input').on('keyup', function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode === 13) 
      alert('enter key event');
});
```

Comment: i try this but not work, the problem is when i did submit on select2, never fire the keydown or keyup or keypress.

Comment: $('select2-search > input.select2-input').on('keyup', function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode === 13) 
      alert('enter key event');
});

tried this?

Comment: Yes and nothing happens

Comment: i have my select2 inside the xeditable, and when did submit the key enter event not fire.

Comment: Apologies but i was making a mistake, and your code helped me in the following form,thank you very much

 
$('.select2-search > input.select2-input').on('keyup', function(e) { if(e.keyCode === 13) alert('enter key event'); });

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Select2 v4. The input added to the end of the DOM when the dropdown opens

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's essentially the same thing:

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress keydown', ".select2-input", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        console.log("Pressed enter!");
    }
});
```

Comment: i try this but not work, the problem is when i did submit on select2, never fire the keydown or keyup or keypress.

Comment: Insert `<input type="text"> </input>` into your DOM. Change ".select2-input" to "input" and verify whether the event is firing upon **ENTER** for either inputs.

Comment: I do not understand what you say

Answer (score 1):

@Anon's code works!

I'm using `Select2 4.0.3` and I just remove `keypress` and `keydown` events:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        alert('Pressed enter!');
    }
});
```